# OSReload PriceId in Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When OSReload is implemented, is there a specific price id?
I can't find any price for OS reloading regardless platforms, Bare Metal and Virtual Device. This function is not charged ? or there is any API to get price for osreloading?

[image: osReloading price in Softlayer portal]
[image]

Comment: When I reload OS as same configuration, SoftLayer charges the price $0.02. Is this a fixed one time charge ? or there is a priceid for reloading OS depending on OSs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The price to reaload OS is the same price as the OS in a order server/VSI. you just need the package that was used to oder the server/VSI and list the prices for that package,the look for the os that you wish.

here an example in Python

https://gist.github.com/softlayer/407058

Let me know if you hava more questions

Regards

Comment: My implementation is installing OS as the same configuration. There is no charge for installing OS with same configuration?

Comment: Nop there is no extra charge, if you wish the same configuration you do not need to send any configuration as parameter you just need to send the ´force´ value